# How best to remove list items in a loop in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, loops

Given the code:

```
var AllItems = new List<CartItem>();

using(var db = new MainContext())
{
    foreach (var item in AllItems)
    {
        if (!db.tblStoreItems.Where(i => i.ID == item.ItemID).Any())
        {
            AllItems.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to remove an item from the List object in a loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several things that are wrong with the loop approach, the main being - you cannot remove items from the collection you're currently iterating over with `foreach` - you will get an exception.

Since your main collection is a `List<T>`, you should use the [`RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method that takes in a predicate. You should also simplify your query like this:

```
AllItems.RemoveAll(item => !db.tblStoreItems.Any(i => i.ID == item.ItemID));
```

Answer (score 9):

I don't think so. If you remove an item from the list on which you are iterating, the results will be securely wrong.

It's best to use an old fashion for - loop in reverse order

```
using(var db = new MainContext()) 
{ 
    for(int x = AllItems.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--) 
    { 
        var item = AllItems[x];
        if (!db.tblStoreItems.Where(i => i.ID == item.ItemID).Any()) 
        { 
            AllItems.RemoveAt(x); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Items are being removed from array and parallely loop is going on for original number of items. Finally it will be crashed on `Index Out of Range`.

Answer (score 1):

That's wrong (the OP's approach) as rightly suggested by Steve (Steve's way is probably the best in terms of performance),

I prefer to store the `'those to be removed'` into a separate list, then you can do e.g.

```
AllItems = AllItems.Except(Items2Remove);
```

That is not best from performance way but for me makes things cleaner - you could also combine with LINQ enumerate - e.g. make IEnumerable from the list of records etc.

hope this helps
EDIT: just to clarify as per Steve's response

Comment: @Steve maybe I put it 'wrong' :) - yours is perfect - I meant 'his approach'. I just prefer going 'twice around', yours is more performant and works just perfect.